# Three doors with equal probability, only first door is correct, what is the expectation of going out?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, expected-value

The following question is taken from [glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.sg/Interview/1-How-do-you-simulate-stock-price-with-VBA-2-Std-3-VaR-4-Three-doors-it-takes-QTN_1355856.htm).

> Three doors, it takes you $1$ minute to go through the first door, it also takes you $1$ minute to go through the second door, it make your speed slow down $\frac{1}{2}$ after going through third door. Only the first door is the right way to go out. You choose each door with the equal probability. How much time will you go out in expectation?

Let $E(X)$ be the required expectation. By law of total expectation, 
$$E(X) = P(\text{first door})E(X\,\vert\,\text{first  door}) + P(\text{second door})E(X\,\vert\,\text{second  door}) + P(\text{third door})E(X\,\vert\,\text{third  door}).$$
Each probability above is $\frac{1}{3}.$ We also know that 
$$E(X\,\vert\,\text{first  door}) = 1, \quad E(X\,\vert\,\text{second  door}) = 1 + E(X).$$
However, I do not know how to calculate 
$$E(X\,\vert\,\text{third door}).$$
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why $E(X\mid \text{second door}=1+E(X)$  This suggests than even after you try the second door, and it doesn't work, you have a $\frac13$ probability of choosing it again.

Comment: @saulspatz:  the usual rule in puzzles like this is that you can't remember which door you tried the last time, so each try is random.  That should be stated in the problem.  If you do remember, the problem is no fun because there are just five cases to consider.

Comment: @RossMillikan Well, it's apparently an interview question, so I didn't  think it was supposed to be fun :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each pass through the third door cuts your speed in half but you go through that door instantly you have 
$$E(X|\text{third door})=2E(X)$$
When you plug this into your equation you will get a contradiction, which means that the sum $E(X)=\sum_{t=0}^\infty tP(t)$ where $P(t)$ is the probability of escape after time $t$ does not converge.

Comment: I will indeed get a contradiction if I plug your equation above into my equation. However, I do not follow your last statement. Why would $E(X)$ diverge?

Comment: Basically $P(t)$ will not decrease fast enough.  It is similar to the [Saint Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox)